# wordpress, passwordhash, in java

Tags: java, wordpress, hash, md5

I have a Java application that needs to communicate with my server application (java application proxy forward by apache).

In my web site, I am using wordpress, so in order to use the same users in my site and in my application, I decided to use the wordpress users table in the db.

I need to be able to create a new user from my application, but I have a problem hashing my password using Java.

How can I hash my password the same way as wordress does in Java?

(I just think it's better then proxy to java and then forward again to wordpress just to create a user)

thank you

Comment: i really dont get it , is MD5 not secure enough ?

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of posts on the net about the algorithm Wordpress uses ([ref1](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-282-password-encoding), [ref2](http://barry.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/mod_auth_mysql-and-phpass/)).  It has changed over different versions of WordPress so you will need to identify your version, identify the algorithm it's using, then see if you can find/build a Java version of that particular algorithm.